# How to paginate using wp_user_query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have been having a hard time doing pagination for a list of users in the backend of my wordpress website using a custom plugin. It actually displays everything with the links but when i click the "Next Page" link it loads and stays on the same instead of moving to page 2. This is my code(I got this from another answer here on stackoverflow but have not succeeded in making the pagination link increment to next page):

```
   function oragatesoft_expert(){

// Pagination vars
$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ? (int) get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo $current_page;
$users_per_page = 2; // RAISE THIS AFTER TESTING ;)

$args = array(
    'number' => $users_per_page, // How many per page
    'paged' => $current_page // What page to get, starting from 1.
);

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$total_users = $users->get_total(); // How many users we have in total (beyond the current page)
$num_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page); // How many pages of users we will need

?>
    <h3>Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $num_pages; ?></h3>
    <p>Displaying <?php echo $users_per_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_users; ?> users</p>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            if ( $users->get_results() ) foreach( $users->get_results() as $user )  {
                $firstname = $user->first_name;
                $lastname = $user->last_name;
                $email = $user->user_email;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html($firstname); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html($lastname); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html($email); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
        <?php
        // Previous page
        if ( $current_page > 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="'. add_query_arg(array('paged' => $current_page-1)) .'">Previous Page</a>';
        }

        // Next page
        if ( $current_page < $num_pages ) {
            echo '<a href="'. add_query_arg(array('paged' => $current_page+1)) .'">Next Page</a>';
        }
        ?>
    </p>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that using something like this would work for anyone else coming across this.

```
$args = array (
    'number' => 1, // use this like you would posts_per_page
    'paged' => 2,
);

$wp_user_query = new \WP_User_Query($args);

// Get the results
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();
```